# What's the benefit of 3-ways comparison operator (<=>) in C++20?

Tags: syntax, comparison, operators, c++20

I know the syntax of it.
I just wondering what's the benefit or whether does it make sens.

Without it, we must code like this:

```
void func1(int x, int y) {
    if( x > y )
        doSomeThing();
    else if( x < y )
        doSomeElse();
    else
        explosive();
}
```

With it, we can do like this:

```
void func1(int x, int y) {
    auto result = x <=> y;
    if( result > 0 )
        doSomeThing();
    else if( result < 0 )
        doSomeElse();
    else
        explosive();
}
```

Except for returning a comparison result, I can **NOT** see any benefit of this feature.
Some one says it can make our codes more readable, but I don't think so.
It's very obvious, the former example has more readability.

As to return a result, like this:

```
int func1(int x, int y) {
    return x <=> y;
}
```

It looks like that we get much more readability, but we still need to check the value with another if/else somewhere, e.g. outside of the func1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can NOT see any benefit of this feature.

Then you are thinking too narrowly about what is actually happening.

Direct use of `<=>` does not exist to serve the needs of `int`s. It can be used for comparing them, but `int`s are not why the functionality exists.

It exists for types that actually have complex comparison logic. Consider `std::string`. To know if one string is "less than" another, you have to iterate through both strings and compare each character. When you find a non-equivalent one, you have your answer.

Your code, when applied to `string`, does the comparison twice: once with less than and once with greater than. The problem is this: the first comparison already found the first non-equal character. But the second comparison *does not know* where that is. So it must start from the very beginning, doing the exact same comparisons the first one did.

That's a lot of repeated work for an answer than the first comparison already computed. In fact, there is a really easy way to compute `<=>` for strings: subtract the corresponding character in the second string from the first. If the value is zero, then they are equal. If the result is negative, the first string is less; if it's positive, the first string is greater.

Which is... exactly what `<=>` returns, isn't it? By using `<=>`, you do two *expensive* comparisons in the space of one; testing the return value is immaterial next to the cost of them.

The more complex your comparison logic, the more you are likely to save with `<=>` if you need to categorize them into less/greater/equal.

It should also be noted that processors often have special opcodes to tell if an integer is negative, zero, or positive. If we look at [the x86 assembly for your integer comparison](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fxdxjW4sn):

```
func1(int, int):                             # @func1(int, int)
        cmp     edi, esi
        jle     .LBB0_1
        jmp     a()@PLT                       # TAILCALL
.LBB0_1:
        jge     .LBB0_2
        jmp     b()@PLT                       # TAILCALL
.LBB0_2:
        jmp     c()@PLT                       # TAILCALL
```

We can see that it only executes `cmp` once; the `jle` and `jge` instructions use the results of the comparison. The `<=>` compiles to the same assembly, so the compiler fully understands these as being synonyms.